# How to ignore the contents of a previously tracked directory in git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) about no longer tracking a previously tracked file, but here is my situation.

I previously committed a directory. I now want to untrack everything in that directory but still track the directory itself.

I have added 
`/auto-save-list/*` to the  `.gitignore` file (the directory I am trying to ignore is the `auto-save-list` directory in the root of the project, and I have run `git rm --cached` but I still have multiple filed from that directory that show up as new when I go to make a commit.  Similarly the files show up in my origin repo.

Can someone help me ignore the contents of the previously tracked file?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only files.  If you untrack everything in that directory, the directory too vanishes, unless you put a file in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
git rm -r --cached auto-save-list/
echo "/auto-save-list/" > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Records untracking of /auto-save-list/ folder"
```

No need for '`*`'

If you still need the directory to be there (versioned in the Git repo, even though Git doesn't track an empty folder), add a dummy file in it.

```
touch auto-save-list/.keep
git add -f auto-save-list/.keep
git commit -m "Record auto-save-list/ folder, while ignoring its content"
```